# composer.json should uses different packages versions depending of php version

Tags: php, composer-php, travis-ci

[**travis-ci**](https://travis-ci.org/) allow run **phpunit** over some PHP versions.

The problem is that my `composer.json` requires `phpunit/phpunit=~4.8`, and on **phpunit 4.8.20** was declared that **PHP 7.0+** isn't supported anymore. This PHP version should uses `phpunit/phpunit=~5.1` that is supported on **PHP 5.6+**.

My package requires runs on **PHP 5.4+**.

I can solve it by unsupporting **PHP 5.4** and **PHP 5.5**, but all tests works perfectly on this versions, and on my country this versions *yet* are used by a lot hosts.

I think that is possible do something like it:

```
"phpunit/phpunit": "if php < 7 then ~4.8 else ~5.1"
```

Maybe `config.platform` help me? I can't understand how it works too.

Answer (score 3):

You can make or-requirements in Composer. If you want to say that PHPUnit can be used in version 4.8 or 5.x, it is:

```
"phpunit/phpunit": "~4.8|~5.0"
```

You have to run `update` in your build script, but Composer will figure it out depending on the PHP version it detects.

It is your responsibility to maintain compatibility of your tests with either version, but Travic will detect failures pretty soon, won't it?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't worked. It keep choicing last available version. :( [travis-ci result](https://travis-ci.org/VanillaPackage/vanilla-permission/jobs/96158817)

Comment: As I mentioned: You have to run `composer update` prior to your test, not `install`, because `install` will install the fixed packages that are defined in `composer.lock`. And when you are at it, you should also define a test run for `composer update --prefer-lowest`, which will install the oldest possible version required. This will reveal backward-incompatible changes in your code that might access new features that are not present in the old version you are requiring.